# Change VS 2017 JavaScript compilation error squiggly line and mark to red

Tags: javascript, ide, visual-studio-2017, settings, intellisense

I have recently moved on from VS 2015 to VS 2017. I thought I had lost the ability for VS to warn me about compile errors in JavaScript, but eventually realized they have changed the color of the squiggly line and the scroll bar mark to light green:

[image: Green Squiggles!]

I cannot for the life of me understand what part of light green spells compilation error...

Is there a way to change this for JavaScript specifically? All other languages appear to be red as expected.

Pre-req:
I have Web Essentials installed
I am using dark theme

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This belongs in [Super User](https://superuser.com/) not Stack Overflow as this is not a programming question.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: From [What can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"if your question generally covers…software tools commonly used by programmers"* VS 2017 qualifies.

Comment: @ Matt - It's not clear what research you've done, for instance, in Tools | Options | Font and Colors....

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I have searched through Font and Colors (as suggested for other issues thought this site), but I do not see anything that helps me out there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Tools | Options | Text Editors | JavaScript/TypeScript | ESLint

[image: Disable ESLint]

I disabled it and now my marks and squiggles are red again!

I looked into ESLint ([ESLint | About](https://eslint.org/docs/about/)) and do not know why I would really (personally) want to enable it (or why it is enabled by default in 2017).

I can add this to a list of things to modify / disable when installing VS 2017 now -- and the list is getting quite large...

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible,you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: @Jack Zhai-MSFT - Done!